# Indexes on small table needing to be constantly rebuilt when server busy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In my SQL database (compatibility level SQL Server 2008, but on SQL Server 2012), I have a small table called Locations: 2036 rows in 21 pages.

"Select * from Locations" will return all rows in a split second. However, after moving to a virtual environment, under heavy load that SQL will hang until I rebuild indexes on that table: "ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.Locations REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)".

And then it's fine. Until it slows down again and I need to rebuild again -- sometimes 5 sec later!

When I run: "DBCC CHECKTable (Locations);", I get "DBCC results for 'Locations'.There are 2036 rows in 21 pages for object "Locations".

Any ideas what this could be or where I should start looking?

Comment: You said it yourself - "after moving to a virtual environment".  Your VM is where you should start.

Comment: What are the stats on your VM?  "Under heavy load" = how many TPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query on the whole table;

```
Select * from Locations
```

will not reference any indexes, and I therefore believe its pure coincidence that an index rebuild is 'solving' the problem. Have you checked for process thread locks on the SQL Server?  There may be some contention on the table that is locking that query.

Comment: I think you're right. If I add WITH (NOLOCK), it returns quickly. The index rebuild probably just freed up the locks. Thanks!